# CentOS 6.1 AMI for running on EC2?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I don't seem to see any public AMI images created for CentOS 6.1. Is there a reason for that? Is it recommended I spin my own up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might have something to do with the fact that CentOS 6.1 was only [released](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2011-December/018312.html) a week ago. You might actually have to wait a little longer to have someone else do the due diligence and assemble a stable AMI or you could [roll your own](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2007-01-03/CreatingAndBundlingAMIs.html).

Comment: Or they can get a Centos 6.0 AMI and do an upgrade to 6.1 with Yum.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Centos 6.0 AMI - update it and then make an AMI out of it

Answer (score 0):

There aren't official CentOS AMI's for 5 or 6.

The Easier option is to use an Image like RightImage ( from RightScale ) which has CentOS 6.x images, customizing it and making an AMI out of it.

I would recommend you checking out Amazon Linux, which is binary compatible with RHEL/CentOS. All the repositories, like EPEL, RPMForge, etc, work and it is even supported by Amazon.